# Websocket gets disconnected several seconds later after handshake in django Channels 2

Tags: python, django, disconnect, channel

WebSocket gets disconnected in django channels2. And before it following error was thrown.

```
2018-06-03 19:05:40,238 - ERROR - server - Exception inside
application: [Errno -2] Name or service not known   File
 "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 241, in _step
     result = coro.throw(exc)   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/consumer.py",
 line 54, in __call__
     await await_many_dispatch([receive, self.channel_receive], self.dispatch)   File
 "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/utils.py",
 line 57, in await_many_dispatch
     await task   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 363, in __iter__
     return self.result()  # May raise too.   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
     raise self._exception   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/utils.py",
 line 49, in await_many_dispatch
     result = task.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
     raise self._exception   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
     result = coro.send(None)   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py",
 line 184, in receive
     self.receive_loop_task.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
     raise self._exception   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
     result = coro.send(None)   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py",
 line 202, in receive_loop
     real_channel, message = await self.receive_single(general_channel)   File
 "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py",
 line 218, in receive_single
     async with self.connection(index) as connection:   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py",
 line 447, in __aenter__
     self.conn = await aioredis.create_redis(**self.kwargs)   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aioredis/commands/__init__.py",
 line 177, in create_redis
     loop=loop)   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aioredis/connection.py",
 line 107, in create_connection
     timeout, loop=loop)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 373, in wait_for
     return (yield from fut)   File "/home/lusine/projects/DjangoTest/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/aioredis/stream.py",
 line 19, in open_connection
     lambda: protocol, host, port, **kwds)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 651, in
 create_connection
     infos = f1.result()   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
     raise self._exception   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):   [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: I forgot to point to redis server host.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using some incorrect address, probably Redis hostname.